# cron job not working but works on terminal

Tags: cron

I created a Python  command that uploads a zip file to an FTP server

I want to run it every 5 minutes using cron jobs.

So I opened crontab using `crontab -e` and I added the following line

[image]

The cron job does not work but when I run `smart-cv.py archive` from the terminal it works and I can see that the zip file is uploaded to the FTP server.

I have already tried restarting the cron server with `service cron restart` but it does not work

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: A general tip to debug cronjobs is to send the full output to a log file, like `*/5 * * * * smart-cv.py archive >> /tmp/user-crontab.log 2>&1`, then open another console and run `tail -f /tmp/user-crontab.log` to see the output live while it runs. You can change the path of the log file to your home folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the complete path of the python file. Change your command to

```
 5 * * * * /path-of-the-file/smart-cv.py archive
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The Python command that I created belongs to a custom module that I deployed. It's located in `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/smart_cv-1.0.0-py3.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts`. When I run `smart-cv.py archive` the terminal automatically searchs in the path so how can i tell cron to do the same ?

Comment: You can add a `PATH=$PATH:xxx` assignment at the top of your crontab (actually anywhere before the command)

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi Please [edit] your question to reflect all the details you posted in the comment. It helps to keep our Q&A style tidy and could also bring more attention since an edited question gets bounced on the homepage.